# How to assign key from button to a state variable

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have the code below and I want to make a post request with the key value from the button. How can I put the value of the selected button key in a state variable that is going to be posted? The variable is `id_troti`, should get the button key value.

```
makeBooking() {
        fetch('https://porsche.e-twow.uk/reactnative/add_rezervare.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                start: this.state.startDate,
                end: this.state.endDate,
                username: this.state.loggedUser,
                id_troti: 2
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.text())  // convert to plain text
        .then(text => console.log(text))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} key={item.id} onPress={
  this.makeBooking.bind(this)
                                }>
                                    <Text style={styles.scooterText}>Scooter-ul {item.id}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
makeBooking = id=> {
        fetch('https://porsche.e-twow.uk/reactnative/add_rezervare.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                start: this.state.startDate,
                end: this.state.endDate,
                username: this.state.loggedUser,
                id_troti: id
            })
        })
        .then(res => res.text())  // convert to plain text
        .then(text => console.log(text))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} key={item.id} onPress={e=>
  this.makeBooking(item.id)
                                }>
                                    <Text style={styles.scooterText}>Scooter-ul {item.id}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
```